# Save data from xml file when internet is available in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, parsexml

I am making an `app` in `android studio` in which i am getting data from `JSON files` and populating it in a spinner. Below is my image of app

[image]

I have two options for saving data with the following conditions.

1. When internet is off the data will be saved into a local `xml` file.
2. When internet is on the app `will` check for the connectivity and if available then it will check the file and then upload it to the server.

For now i am able to implement the both points separately i.e. I have created a method which will check for the connectivity of the internet. Passed this method into a condition and if the connection is available it will save the data into a local file aka `xml` file and if internet is not available then it will save the new data only to the server.

My script is below

```
require_once ('config.php');

$return_arr = array();

$ref_no = ($_POST['ref_no']);
$meter_type = ($_POST['meter_type']);
$lattitude = ($_POST['lattitude']);
$longitude = ($_POST['longitude']);
$site_status = ($_POST['site_status']);
$comm_status = ($_POST['comm_status']);
$pole_type = ($_POST['pole_type']);
$meter_placement = ($_POST['meter_placement']);
$date_time = ($_POST['datetime']);



$record_save = "INSERT INTO `survey`(`s_id`,`ref_no`,`meter_type`, `lattitude`,`longitude`,`site_status`,`comm_status`,`pole_type`,`meter_placement`, `datetime`) values (NULL,'".$ref_no."','".$meter_type."','".$lattitude."','".$longitude."','".$site_status."','".$comm_status."','".$pole_type."','".$meter_placement."','".$date_time."')";
mysqli_query ($con,$record_save);
$row_array['errorcode1'] = 1;
```

I am saving all the data in a string format like below

```
String DateTime,refr_no, meter_type, Latitude, Longitude, site_status, comm_status, pole_type,rb_text;
```

On button click i am asking a `permission` for saving file in local storage and then on `permission granted` i have placed checks like below

```
btn_save_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(refr_no == "Select a reference number" || meter_type == "Select Meter Type" || Latitude == " " || Longitude == ""
                    || site_status == "Select Site Status" || comm_status == "" || pole_type == "Select pole type" || DateTime == "" )
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Data not saved.... you must be missing some thing.. Please check!!! " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

            }else {

                new TedPermission(MainActivity.this)
                        .setPermissionListener(ListenerSaveData)
                        .setRationaleMessage("This activity will need your permission to save file ")
                        .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        .check();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }

        }
    });

 final PermissionListener ListenerSaveData = new PermissionListener() {
              @Override
              public void onPermissionGranted() {
                  if(refr_no == "Select a reference number" || meter_type == "Select Meter Type" || Latitude == " " || Longitude == ""
                          || site_status == "Select Site Status" || comm_status == "" || pole_type == "Select pole type" || DateTime == "" )
                  {
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Data not saved.... you must be missing some thing.. Please check!!! " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                  }else {

                      if (!isOnline()) {
                          try {
                              File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
                              file.createNewFile();
                              FileOutputStream fileos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
                              XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
                              StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                              xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
                              xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "record");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "ref_no");
                              xmlSerializer.text(refr_no);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "ref_no");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "meter_type");
                              xmlSerializer.text(meter_type);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "meter_type");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "lat");
                              xmlSerializer.text(Latitude);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "lat");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "long");
                              xmlSerializer.text(Longitude);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "long");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "site_status");
                              xmlSerializer.text(site_status);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "site_status");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "communication_status");
                              xmlSerializer.text(comm_status);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "communication_status");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "pole_type");
                              xmlSerializer.text(pole_type);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "pole_type");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "meter_placement");
                              xmlSerializer.text(rb_text);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "meter_placement");
                              xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "date_time");
                              xmlSerializer.text(DateTime);
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "date_time");
                              xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "record");
                              xmlSerializer.endDocument();
                              xmlSerializer.flush();
                              String dataWrite = writer.toString();
                              fileos.write(dataWrite.getBytes());
                              fileos.close();
                          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          } catch (IOException e) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                          dd_ref.setSelection(0);
                          dd_pole_type.setSelection(0);
                          dd_site_status.setSelection(0);
                          dd_m_type.setSelection(0);

                          _latitude.setText("");
                          _longitude.setText("");
                          comment.setText("");
                          DateTime = "";
                          refr_no = "";
                          Latitude = "";
                          Longitude = "";
                          site_status = "";
                          comm_status = "";
                          pole_type = "";
                          rb_text = "";
                          rg_meter_placement.clearCheck();
                      }else if (isOnline())
                      {
                          new SaveData().execute(refr_no,meter_type,Latitude,Longitude,site_status,comm_status,pole_type,rb_text,DateTime);
                      }
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onPermissionDenied(ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {

              }
          };
```

Here the `isOnline` method is checking the internet connectivity as below

```
protected boolean isOnline() {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Internet is Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Internet is NOT Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

For `SaveData()` method the code is below

```
private class SaveData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    String res;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                "", "Saving Data Please wait...");
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        res = null;
        PutUtility put = new PutUtility();

        put.setParam("ref_no",params[0].toString());
        put.setParam("meter_type", params[1].toString());
        put.setParam("lattitude", params[2].toString());
        put.setParam("longitude", params[3].toString());
        put.setParam("site_status",params[4].toString());
        put.setParam("comm_status",params[5].toString());
        put.setParam("pole_type",params[6].toString());
        put.setParam("meter_placement",params[7].toString());
        put.setParam("datetime",params[8].toString());


        try {
            res = put.postData("http://192.168.100.12:8000/new/post_data.php");
            Log.v("res", res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String res) {

        if(refr_no == "Select a reference number" || meter_type == "Select Meter Type" || Latitude == " " || Longitude == ""
                || site_status == "Select Site Status" || comm_status == "" || pole_type == "Select pole type" || DateTime == "" )
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Data not saved.... you must be missing some thing.. Please check!!! " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Data Saved Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            dd_ref.setSelection(0);
            dd_pole_type.setSelection(0);
            dd_site_status.setSelection(0);
            dd_m_type.setSelection(0);

            _latitude.setText("");
            _longitude.setText("");
            comment.setText("");
            DateTime = "";
            refr_no = "";
            Latitude = "";
            Longitude = "";
            site_status = "";
            comm_status = "";
            pole_type = "";
            rb_text = "";
            rg_meter_placement.clearCheck();
        }
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);


    }

}
```

While the `PutUtility` class is below

```
public class PutUtility {

private Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
private static HttpURLConnection httpConnection;
private static BufferedReader reader;
private StringBuffer response;


public void setParam(String key, String value) {
    params.put(key, value);
}

public String postData(String Url) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String key : params.keySet()) {
        String value = null;
        value = params.get(key);


        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append("&");
        }
        sb.append(key + "=" + value);
    }

    try {
        // Defined URL  where to send data

        URL url = new URL(Url);

        URLConnection conn = null;
        conn = url.openConnection();

        // Send POST data request
        httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = null;

        wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(sb.toString());
        wr.flush();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    return response.toString();
}}
```

I want to implement the second point that whenever the `app` is connected to the internet then all the data in the file (xml file) will be uploaded to the server.

As a newbie i don't have any idea how to do it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look into Realm instead of XML files.

Comment: @BradleyWilson you mean to say [this one](https://realm.io/) ?

Comment: I do mean that one, yes.

Comment: @BradleyWilson i don't want to use `realm`

Comment: You can use broadcast receiver with alarm manager to continuosly check for the interent connection, when the connection is available you can upload the data to the server, meanwhile you can continue to save it locally.

Comment: @AndroidHacker can you please provide a tutorial it will be very helpful for me

Comment: you can use google for it there are plenty of tutorials available for this.